# 'boolean java.lang.Class.isInterface()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, parcelable, android-13

I'm facing this crash on Android 13 at following code.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Class.isInterface()' on a null object reference
```

Code:

```
val temp = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) 
    bundle.getParcelable(ARG_TAG, Tab::class.java)
else 
    bundle.getParcelable(ARG_TAG)
```

DataClass (Tab) is as follow:

```
@Keep
@Parcelize
data class Tab(
    val data: List<String>? = null,
    val icon: String? = null,
    val provider: String? = null,
    val subtype: String? = null,
    val title: String,
    val items: Int = 0
) : Parcelable
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found solution, by using recommended approach for Android-13 `BundleCompat`

```
val temp = BundleCompat.getParcelable(bundle, ARG_TAG, Tab::class.java)
```

Comment: How about for Activity Intent? This issue seems plague the Android 13 so bad that it is also only showing in release build.

Comment: you can update for intent too,

Comment: the check is already done inside. `BuildCompat.isAtLeastU()`

Comment: thanks for sharing, It is deprecated and stated as "Android UpsideDownCase is a finalized release and this method is no longer " +
            "necessary. It will be removed in a future release of this library. Instead, use " +
            "`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34`."

Comment: Thank you. I had the same problem and your solution fixed it for me too. I've been a professional developer for nearly 30 years and I've never come across a platform as  fiddly to work with as Android!

Comment: for anyone wondering what is wrong with api 33 implementation here is the description by google dev https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240585930#comment6

Comment: Note also ``IntentCompat.getParcelableExtra``