# Android 13 Tiramisu Bug with Parcelable

Tags: android, android-13, android-tiramisu

There is a bug with Android SDK 33 that crashes the app only in release build when using the new `getParcelableExtra` or more likely `getParcelableArrayListExtra` since this is where I get the issue.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Class.isInterface()' on a null object reference
```

There seems to be a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76614322/12204620) for Fragment but no alternative for Activity. There is also an issue [tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240585930) but was probably deleted.

Below is the code that I am using.

```
/**
 * Extension for getting Parcelable Intent with backward compatibility support.
 * */
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Activity.getParcelableIntent(key: String): T? {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
        intent.getParcelableExtra(key, T::class.java)
    else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        intent.getParcelableExtra(key)
    }
}

/**
 * Extension for getting Parcelable ArrayList Intent with backward compatibility support.
 * */
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Activity.getParcelableArrayListIntent(key: String): java.util.ArrayList<T>? {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
        intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(key, T::class.java)
    else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(key)
    }
}
```

In Activity

```
val relatedNews = getParcelableArrayListIntent<NewsDataDomain>(INTENT_NEWS_LIST)
```

Despite the debug and release having both configuration on minify and shrink settings I only encounter the issue above in release build.

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            firebaseCrashlytics {
                // No need during development, enabling it also prevents Gradle to work offline
                mappingFileUploadEnabled false
            }

            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Also tried adding `@Keep` annotation in the domain data class but still no luck.

Comment: Why aren't you using the [IntentCompat API](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/IntentCompat#getParcelableArrayExtra(android.content.Intent,java.lang.String,java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E))?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, oh crap. I really missed that one. Thanks a lot, still that can really be problematic as the issue only showed on release build. It passed on both Test Lab and end to end testing using debug build so glad it only reached internal release track.

Comment: Funnily enough even official compat api checks internally that API >= 34. So there's actually no solution just use deprecated method for one more version.

Comment: @Pawel you are right, the checking against Tiramisu seems useless here. I wonder why it worked on debug build but not in release build.

Comment: That's because API 33's behavior is [fundamentally broken](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240585930#comment6). You should absolutely not use them ever on API 33.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: FWIW, that issue is not public.

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake, that explains why it is broken and release build and why only `getParcelableArrayListExtra` is crashing but not `getParcelableExtra`

Comment: Please check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77583908/2068397. It is working for me